# How to click a button from multiple buttons on same page in selenium web driver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

On web page, multiple select-buttons are displayed accordingly. i need to select only the first select from the web page. Every time the Id is getting changed.
how i can handle it using Selenium-Web driver (java). below is the HTML:

```
<div id="start-button-65312" class="start-button1" 
onclick="loadCreateClaimForm('65312');">Select</div>

<div id="start-button-88531" class="start-button1" onclick="loadCreateClaimForm('88531');">Select</div>

<div id="start-button-96532" class="start-button1" onclick="loadCreateClaimForm('96532');">Select</div>
```

Comment: Please add more information. For example, html example code, your languaje code (Java, Python, C), and more relevant information to help you.

Comment: below is the HTML:


1. <div id="start-button-65312" class="start-button1" onclick="loadCreateClaimForm('65312');">Select</div>
2. <div id="start-button-77532" class="start-button1" onclick="loadCreateClaimForm('77532');">Select</div>
3. <div id="start-button-88513" class="start-button1" onclick="loadCreateClaimForm('88513');">Select</div>

Comment: You need to show us a bit more of the `outerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use e.g. findElements and use xpath for the identification of your elements. If you always use start-button1 as your class, you could e.g. do something as follows:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("....");
List<WebElement> allbuttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='start-button1']"));
```

That would give you all the buttons. Thus, based on the list of buttons, you can access the different buttons, e.g. based on the index (0, 1 etc.)

```
WebElement button = allbuttons.get(..); //e.g. get(0) for the first
```

You can also check out [Getting Started (Selenium)](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: After get allbuttons list, you should get the first one: `WebElement firstSelect = allbuttons.get(1);`

Comment: Yes, of course, after he has the list, he can access the corresponding button he wants to access.

Comment: I actually prefer identifying the elements based on their ids. However, obviously this only works if these do not change constantly. An upvote/accepted answer would be nice if that helped you ;)